# build a docker image ros2 , when try tu run . install/setup.bash in dockerfile no works

Tags: dockerfile, ros2

i have the next problem:

i try to build a docker image with ros2, in which a code package is downloaded which will be built using the colcon build method.

but when I try to run last of. install / setup.bash doesn't work for me.

I already tried to put it in a script and copy it to the dockerfile but it didn't work

any ideas

here I leave the docker file

```
FROM osrf/ros:dashing-desktop

WORKDIR /home

COPY mobilidad.sh .
RUN bash mobilidad.sh


ENV ROS2_WS cleanmyway/test_ws
RUN mkdir -p ${ROS2_WS}/src/demo_py
COPY ./ ${ROS2_WS}/src/demo_py

WORKDIR ${ROS2_WS}

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN colcon build
RUN . install/setup.bash
```

note: mobilidad.sh is a script that dowload de code from github, this works fine

Comment: I don't know which part doesn't work. Could you share the error message?

Comment: i try to build a ros2 package inside docker but the last comand install/setup.bash doesn't work, and when try run the code I get this error "Package not found", i try:

Comment: i try:

- insert the command as scritpt in the dockerfile but not work.

- run de command in dockerfile but not work.

Comment: could you pass the whole output from docker build?

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to find a solution,

building the dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM osrf/ros:dashing-desktop
WORKDIR /home
COPY mobilidad.sh . 
RUN bash mobilidad.sh

ENV ROS2_WS cleanmyway/test_ws
RUN mkdir -p ${ROS2_WS}

WORKDIR ${ROS2_WS}

RUN colcon build
RUN echo "source install/setup.bash" >> /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash
```

and when i run the ros2 command works fine

but anyway thanks for the help. :)
note: i'm not sure if the better form but works for me